# Ubuntu Mate (ARM) not installing on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: arm, raspberrypi

I have a `Raspberry Pi 3` with `Raspbian` installed on it.

If I insert a SD card with `Ubuntu Mate (ARM) 14.04` on it, I can't even get to the colorful boot screen (boot loader?). I've tried various SD cards with the same results. I tried those same SD cards on a `Raspberry Pi 2 model B` and they work fine, so I've determined it's not the installation media, it's something with the software.

How can I install `Ubuntu Mate (ARM)` on a raspberry pi 3?

## Solution

Based on the accepted answer I performed the following on Mac `OS X` 10.11.3 (El Capitan):

- Downloaded Ubuntu Mate from the Canadian mirror (I'm in NY)
- Decompressed `ubuntu-mate-15.10.3-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.xz` file by double clicking it
- Opened terminal (CMD+space, "terminal", `enter`)
- `$ diskutil list` my SD was listed as `/dev/disk1`
- `$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1`
- `$ sudo dd if=Downloads/ubuntu-mate-15.10.3-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi-2.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1024m`

I modified a line in `config.txt` that is specific for my waveshare screen to display, unmounted, and took out the SD card to plug it in the rpi3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi 3 uses a completely different SOC (BCM 2837). The build your are running only supports the BCM2835 and BCM2836.

**There is a new build that adds support for the Pi 3's SOC. Download it [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-for-raspberry-pi-3/).**